# JQuery ajax() done / fail callbacks not returning upon status 200

Tags: javascript, jquery, servlets

I'm trying to post a form data using JQuery to a remote servlet. 
I can see that the server receives the data and also returns status code 200 and a response string of "{result: 'success'}" 
But the ajax call doesn't return with the done or fail functions (if I add an always function than I can see that it is being called)
Here's a code snippet of the client side:

`

```
var dataParams = 'email='+email+'&password='+password;
var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8888/signup';

var jxhr = $.ajax({
  type : "POST",
  url : url,
  data : dataParams,// serializes the form's elements.
  dataType: "json",
  done: function() {
     console.log("done!");
     hideSignUp();
     showThankYou(); },
  fail: function() {
     console.log("fail!");
      }
  });
```

`

Seems like I'm missing out on something, but can't seem to find what.
Note that I'm using JQuery 1.8.3 so success is deprecated.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Try with **success** instead of **done** and **error** instead of **fail**.

Comment: @Dim13i - I already tried it, and btw - I'm using JQuery 1.8.3 so it success is deprecated.

Comment: Have you opened your console to see if there are any request errors, such as same-origin? if the success isn't being called, the error should be getting called. `fail` as an option to `$.ajax` is undocumented, i've never tried it that way either so i don't know if it works. It should be `error` and `success` as mentioned previously. The option `success` and `error` are not depreciated, only the matching methods of the `jqXHR` are depreciated. (for example, `$.ajax(...).success()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8888/signup";
var jxhr = $.ajax({
  type : "POST",
  url : url,
  data : dataParams,// serializes the form's elements.
  dataType: "json"
  }).done(function() {
     console.log("done!");
     hideSignUp();
     showThankYou(); 
  }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
     console.log(textStatus);
});
```

Comment: you should be logging the arguments inside of .fail so that the reason will be logged too, otherwise it's pretty useless information.

Comment: the 3rd is the most important, it would be the one that says "parseerror"

Comment: Weird that it was a syntax issue, but it actually solved it - Thanks @KevinB!

Answer (score 0):

Try chaining your callbacks, rather than setting them as object fields:

```
 $.ajax({
  type : "POST",
  url : url,
  data : dataParams,// serializes the form's elements.
  dataType: "json"
  }).done(function (xhrResponse) {
    console.log("done!");
    hideSignUp();
    showThankYou();
  }).fail(function (xhrResponse, textStatus) {
    console.log(textStatus);
  }).always( function () {
    console.log("I'm done with this.");
  });
```

By chaining your callbacks, you guarantee execution of at least one (complete).

Comment: which is exactly what @idmean proposed. Sorry for the duplication